# multiple requests to an api

Tags: python-requests, axios

[image]
Hi I'm trying to make multiple requests to the finnhub api using stock tickers from my own API and store them.Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you say "where am I going wrong" are you getting error messages, or is the code not functioning as expected yet running?

Comment: In the end I went with Firebase.